# Add multiple columns from one function call in Python Polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I would like to add multiple columns at once to a Polars dataframe, where each column derives from the same object (for a row), by creating the object only once and then returning a method of that object for each column. Here is a simplified example using a `range` object:

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'x': [11, 22],
})

def uses_object(x):
    r = list(range(0, x))
    c10 = r.count(10)
    c12 = r.count(12)
    return c10, c12

df = df.with_columns(
    count_of_10 = pl.col('x').map_elements(lambda x: uses_object(x)[0]),
    count_of_12 = pl.col('x').map_elements(lambda x: uses_object(x)[1]),
)

print(df)
```

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────┬─────────────┬─────────────┐
│ x   ┆ count_of_10 ┆ count_of_12 │
│ --- ┆ ---         ┆ ---         │
│ i64 ┆ i64         ┆ i64         │
╞═════╪═════════════╪═════════════╡
│ 11  ┆ 1           ┆ 0           │
│ 22  ┆ 1           ┆ 1           │
└─────┴─────────────┴─────────────┘
```

I tried multiple assignment

```
df = df.with_columns(
    count_of_10, count_of_12 = uses_object(pl.col('x')),
)
```

but got error

```
NameError
name 'count_of_10' is not defined.
```

Can I change the code to call `uses_object` only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you return a dictionary from your function:

```py
return dict(count_of_10=c10, count_of_12=c12)
```

You will get a struct column:

```py
df.with_columns(
   count = pl.col('x').map_elements(uses_object)
)
```

```py
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬───────────┐
│ x   ┆ count     │
│ --- ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ struct[2] │
╞═════╪═══════════╡
│ 11  ┆ {1,0}     │
│ 22  ┆ {1,1}     │
└─────┴───────────┘
```

Which you can [`.unnest()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.unnest.html#polars.DataFrame.unnest) into individual columns.

```py
df.with_columns(
   count = pl.col('x').map_elements(uses_object)
).unnest('count')
```

```py
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────┬─────────────┬─────────────┐
│ x   ┆ count_of_10 ┆ count_of_12 │
│ --- ┆ ---         ┆ ---         │
│ i64 ┆ i64         ┆ i64         │
╞═════╪═════════════╪═════════════╡
│ 11  ┆ 1           ┆ 0           │
│ 22  ┆ 1           ┆ 1           │
└─────┴─────────────┴─────────────┘
```

As for your current approach, you would call it once and then use Polars list methods to extract the values in a separate `.with_columns` / `.select` e.g.

```py
df.with_columns(
   count = pl.col('x').map_elements(uses_object)
).with_columns(
   count_of_10 = pl.col('count').list.first(),
   count_of_12 = pl.col('count').list.last(),
).drop('count')
```

Comment: Thanks! I used your first suggestion: I like how it puts all the return information (column names and values) in one place, namely uses_object().

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`to_struct`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.list.to_struct.html) and [`unnest()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.unnest.html) to convert returned list to separate columns:

```py
df.with_columns(
    cnt=pl.col('x').map_elements(uses_object)
).with_columns(
    pl.col('cnt').list.to_struct(fields=['count_of_10','count_of_12'])
).unnest('cnt')

┌─────┬─────────────┬─────────────┐
│ x   ┆ count_of_10 ┆ count_of_12 │
│ --- ┆ ---         ┆ ---         │
│ i64 ┆ i64         ┆ i64         │
╞═════╪═════════════╪═════════════╡
│ 11  ┆ 1           ┆ 0           │
│ 22  ┆ 1           ┆ 1           │
└─────┴─────────────┴─────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks. That gave an error as written, but worked fine, including naming the unnested columns correctly, when I removed the second with_columns clause--this worked:
df = df.with_columns(
    cnt=pl.col('x').map_elements(uses_object)
).unnest('cnt')